# In Ruby, should I use control flow to initialize an accumulator inside a loop?

Tags: ruby, initialization, accumulate

Is it good practice to initialize an accumulator like this?

```
100.times do
  @accumulator = (@accumulator || 0) + 1
end
```

Or should I just initialize it outside the loop and do:

```
@accumulator = 0   
100.times do
  @accumulator += 1
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, I'd normally initialize outside the loop.

However, I would say best practice is to use higher order functions in block form that negates the need for an explicit loop.

```
@accumulator = 100.times.reduce do |memo, element|
  memo + element
end
```

Or, in this case you could even use a symbol to specify the method as so:

```
@accumulator = 100.times.reduce(:+)
```

This applies the "+" method to each pair in turn.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Answer (score 0):

I like the second one. but if you are looking for a acumulator for .times method you could use

```
100.times do |accumulator|
  p accumulator
end
```

the only difference with yours examples is that you have an object attribute as accumulattor, so if you need that attibute for latter usage, you could do something like this

```
100.times do |c|
  @accumulator = c
end
```